# Add aggregate of all data to boxplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have a dataset with scores for different domains. So this can be thought of as a DataFrame with columns `domain` and `score`. I want to draw box plots for each domain. This is quite easy. With seaborn, it looks like this:

```py
import seaborn as sns
data = {"domain": ["econ", "econ", "public_affairs", "culture", "communication", "public_affairs", "communication",  "culture", "public_affairs", "econ",  "culture", "econ", "communication"],
        "score": [0.25, 0.3, 0.5684, 0.198, 0.15, 0.486, 0.78, 0.84, 0.48, 0.81, 0.1, 0.23, 0.5]}
ax = sns.boxplot(x="score", y="domain", data=data)
```

Which results in the following image:

[image: boxplot]

However, I wish to add another tick to the y-axis, where a box plot is drawn for *all* the scores, regardless of their domain, with the tick label "all". It would be perfect if this new "all" box plot could be separated from the other data with a horizontal line to make clear that "all" is not a domain in itself.

I mashed something together in a photo editor program to illustrate what I am looking for, so it would be something like this. Particularly important are the shared axes between all of the plots.

[image: merged plots]

My best attempt was the following, which does not look a lot like what I desire in the example above.

```py
import seaborn as sns
data = {"domain": ["econ", "econ", "public_affairs", "culture", "communication", "public_affairs", "communication",  "culture", "public_affairs", "econ",  "culture", "econ", "communication"],
        "score": [0.25, 0.3, 0.5684, 0.198, 0.15, 0.486, 0.78, 0.84, 0.48, 0.81, 0.1, 0.23, 0.5]}
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

sns.boxplot(ax=axes[0], x="score", y="domain", data=data)
all_box = sns.boxplot(ax=axes[1], data=data["score"], orient="h")
```

[image: attempt]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `gridspec_kw` the set the ratios between the plots (e.g. `[1,4]` as one subplot has 4 times as many boxes). The spacing between the subplots can be fine-tuned via `hspace`.  `axes[0].set_yticklabels()` lets you set the label.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {"domain": ["econ", "econ", "public_affairs", "culture", "communication", "public_affairs", "communication",  "culture", "public_affairs", "econ",  "culture", "econ", "communication"],
        "score": [0.25, 0.3, 0.5684, 0.198, 0.15, 0.486, 0.78, 0.84, 0.48, 0.81, 0.1, 0.23, 0.5]}
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True,
                         gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 4], 'hspace': 0})
sns.set_style('white')
sns.boxplot(ax=axes[0], data=data["score"], orient="h", color='0.6')
axes[0].set_yticklabels(['All'])
sns.boxplot(ax=axes[1], x="score", y="domain", palette='Set2', data=data)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot together with overall box]

An alternative approach is to concatenate the data with a copy and a label that's `"All"` everywhere. For a pandas dataframe you could use `df.copy()` and `pd.concat()`. With just a dictionary of lists, you could simply duplicate the lists.

This way all boxes have exactly the same thickness. As it uses just one `ax`, it combines more easily with other subplots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {"domain": ["econ", "econ", "public_affairs", "culture", "communication", "public_affairs", "communication",  "culture", "public_affairs", "econ",  "culture", "econ", "communication"],
        "score": [0.25, 0.3, 0.5684, 0.198, 0.15, 0.486, 0.78, 0.84, 0.48, 0.81, 0.1, 0.23, 0.5]}

data_concatenated = {"domain": ['All'] * len(data["domain"]) + data["domain"],
                     "score": data["score"] * 2}

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
palette = ['yellow'] + list(plt.cm.Set2.colors)
ax = sns.boxplot(x="score", y="domain", palette=palette, data=data_concatenated)
ax.axhline(0.5, color='0.5', ls=':')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot of concatenated dataframe]

Here is another example, working with pandas and seaborn's flights dataset. It shows different ways to make the summary stand out without adding an extra horizontal line:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')
flights_all = flights.copy()
flights_all['year'] = 'All'

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
palette = ['crimson'] + sns.color_palette('crest', len(flights['year'].unique()))

ax = sns.boxplot(x="passengers", y="year", palette=palette, orient='h', data=pd.concat([flights_all, flights]))
ax.axhspan(-0.5, 0.5, color='0.85', zorder=-1)
# ax.axhline(0.5, color='red', ls=':') # optional separator line
# ax.get_yticklabels()[0].set_color('crimson')
ax.get_yticklabels()[0].set_weight('bold')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplots with summary, flights dataset]

Comment: This is great, thanks! One tiny question: I find that in my case the space between the horizontal line and the boxplots is very small so it almost appears as if the the line is part of the boxplot. Is there anyway to increase the vertical space between the line and subplots?

Comment: If you are referring to the first solution, there you can do e.g. `axes[0].set_ylim([0.7, -0.7])`. You could also change the spines between the subplots to be thinner or less dark.  For the plot with only one subplot, moving things would be a lot harder.

Comment: Instead of a line, you could change the background behind the summary boxplot. E.g. `ax.axhspan(-0.5, 0.5, color='0.8', zorder=-1)`.    Or you could choose the color of the box sufficiently different from the rest, making things clear without a division line.

Comment: `sns.violinplot(..., scale='width')` or `sns.boxenplot(....)` (a recursive variant of a boxplot) might also be interesting.

Comment: Combining the data can be consolidated into a single step using `.assign`: `data = pd.concat([flights[['month', 'passengers']].copy().assign(year='All'), flights], ignore_index=True)`. It should be noted for plotting that the order the DataFrames are concatenated does matter. If the order is reversed, `1949` will be crimson and `'All'` will be at the bottom. Or `flights.iloc[:, [1, 2]]` instead of `flights[['month', 'passengers']]`.