# Adding a new box plot to chart based on dataframe column in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I have the following dataframe:

```
   Month        Period     Value
---------------------------------
 January      Period 1        34
 January      Period 1        34 
 January      Period 1        75 
...
February      Period 1        45
February      Period 1        77
February      Period 1        45  
...
     May      Period 2        24
     May      Period 2        26
     May      Period 2        44
... 
November      Period 3        76  
November      Period 3        25
November      Period 3        74 
...
December      Period 3        76  
December      Period 3        96
December      Period 3        58
```

From this dataframe, I want to produce a chart with 4 box plots. First, I want to create three box plots, plotting the "Value" column, but with a separate box plot for each "Period" (1, 2, and 3). And so I use this code:

```
df.boxplot(column = 'Value', by = 'Period');
plt.suptitle("")
plt.title("Value for each Period")
plt.ylim(0, 5)
plt.ylabel("Value")
```

This produces a single chart with 3 box plots (1 for each period), with "Value" plotted on the y-axis.

Now, I want to create another box plot of the "Value" column, but rather than being indexed by whichever "Period" it is, I want to add a box plot using all data from the entire "Value" column, labelled "Annual" average. This all needs to be in the same chart, and so for box plots in one chart. How can I simply add this fourth "Annual" box plot to the same chart based on the entire "Value" column? I am using python.

Comment: Your question is very similar to [Add aggregate of all data to boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70693038/add-aggregate-of-all-data-to-boxplots), at least if using seaborn is an option.  The same solution (`pd.concat()` of the dataframe together with a modified copy) would also work directly with pandas. See the last part of the answer, which uses a dataframe with flights.

Comment: `df_all = df.copy(); df_all['Period'] = 'Annual'; df_concat = pd.concat([df_all, df]); df_concat.boxplot(column='Value', by='Period')`

Comment: Your code suggestion there solved it! Thank you very much! Though I see that there are to overlapping bunched together titles at the top of the chart reading: "Boxplot grouped by Period" and "Value", and I am not sure how to delete them and just use "Value" as the title.

Comment: Pandas sets a title, which you can change afterwards. `plt.title("Value")` should work, just as in your own example. Or catch the `ax`: `ax=df_concat.boxplot(....)` and then `ax.set_title(...)`.

Comment: Great! Thank you!